# Ubuntu Software Updater just exits, does nothing

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 20.04, desktop, and wish to upgrade to 22.04.

I already updated, upgraded, all packages and restarted.

I launch Software Updater, it tells me all packages are up to date but 22.04 is available, do I wish to upgrade.

I hit "Upgrade", after a while the Software Updater exits silently, and that's it.  Nothing happens.

I try again, same thing, nothing.

What to do?

Comment: open a terminal and execute `sudo do-release-upgrade`, as explained [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html). Copy the errors into your question  (**not** into the comments)

Comment: command line worked;  I think the graphical Updater needs to be fixed.  I am a software eng myself, to have software exit without any error message is simply bad engineering.